# How to get the 10 last modifications with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm started to work with TortoiseSVN and I need to get 10 last modifications. I tried reading the manual on how to filter, but with no luck.

Any advice?

Comment: For a file or for the entire project?

Comment: @Oscar Gomez for entire project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TortoiseSVN you can use the *Show log* menu, it will open a new window.

At the bottom of that window, click the *Show All* button and choose *Show range...*, then you can select the range of revisions for which you want to see the logs.

You can also use the `svn` command line client like this:

```
svn log https://path/to/your/repo -rHEAD:0 -l 10
```

where `-l` stands for `--limit`